# How to select css variable and assign style value to another element

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to select the css variable `--bgcolor` of the element being hovered and assign that value to the `body` css

Here is my current attempt, any suggestions?

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var boxList = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

  var box = Array.prototype.slice.call(boxList);
  box.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {
      var newbg = el.style.background;
      body.style.background = newbg;
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: var(--bgcolor);
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: var(--bgcolor);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #FF0000"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #00FF00"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #0000FF"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle()`. If want to get the variable then you need to use `getPropertyValue()` with computedStyle. Otherwise you can directly get `background` property from computedStlye

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var boxList = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

  var box = Array.prototype.slice.call(boxList);
  box.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {
  
      var newbg = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--bgcolor')
      
      body.style.background = newbg;
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: var(--bgcolor);
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: var(--bgcolor);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #FF0000"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #00FF00"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #0000FF"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access CSS variables in your Javascript code through the `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` methods as shown below:

```
getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--bgcolor');
```

So in your case, set `newbg` to the line above instead of `el.style.background`.

If you encounter any problems or questions while implementing my solution, please tell me in a comment.

**Edit:** Looks like someone beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const bodyCol = window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('--bgcolor')
const hover = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("box")) {
    const bg  = window.getComputedStyle(tgt).getPropertyValue('--bgcolor')
    body.style.backgroundColor = e.type === "mouseover" ? bg : bodyCol;
  }  
};

document.getElementById("colors").addEventListener("mouseover",hover)
document.getElementById("colors").addEventListener("mouseout",hover)
```

```css
body {
  background: var(--bgcolor);
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: var(--bgcolor);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="colors">
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #FF0000"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #00FF00"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--bgcolor: #0000FF"></div>
</div>
</body>
```